# ActiveRecord model for upvotes and downvotes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

How can I make my model DRY and KISS?

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_type, :item_id, :rating, :voters_up, :voters_down
  serialize :voters_up, Hash
  serialize :voters_down, Hash
  belongs_to :ranks, :polymorphic => true

  def self.up(item, user, iteration = 1)
    @rating = Rating.where(item_type: item.class.name, item_id: item.id).first
    @rating = Rating.create(item_type: item.class.name, 
                            item_id: item.id, 
                            rating: 0, 
                            voters_up: {users:[]}, voters_down: {users:[]}) unless @rating

    changed = nil
    if !@rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.increment(:rating, 1)
        @rating.voters_up[:users] << user.id
        changed = true
      end
    end

    if @rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.decrement(:rating, 1)
        @rating.voters_up[:users].delete user.id
        changed = true
      end
    end

    if @rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.voters_up[:users] << user.id
        @rating.voters_down[:users].delete user.id
        @rating.increment(:rating, 2)
        changed = true
      end
    end

    @rating.save
    item.update_attribute(:rating_value, @rating.rating)
  end

  def self.down(item, user, iteration = 1)
    @rating = Rating.where(item_type: item.class.name, item_id: item.id).first
    @rating = Rating.create(item_type: item.class.name, 
                            item_id: item.id, 
                            rating: 0, 
                            voters_up: {users:[]}, voters_down: {users:[]}) unless @rating

    changed = nil
    if !@rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.decrement(:rating, 1)
        @rating.voters_down[:users] << user.id
        changed = true
      end
    end

    if @rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.increment(:rating, 1)
        @rating.voters_down[:users].delete user.id
        changed = true
      end
    end

    if @rating.voters_up[:users].include?(user.id) && !@rating.voters_down[:users].include?(user.id)
      if changed.nil?
        @rating.voters_down[:users] << user.id
        @rating.voters_up[:users].delete user.id
        @rating.decrement(:rating, 2)
        changed = true
      end
    end

    @rating.save
    item.update_attribute(:rating_value, @rating.rating)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 2-part answer: First, a direct answer to your question, and then an alternative approach to the whole thing.

**DRYing the current implementation**
Firstly, I'd make sure that every "item" `has_one :rating`. Right now, you're doing a lot of manual record creation, and `Rating` has to leave all of its attributes accessible to mass-assignment. It'd also be nicer to simply say `question.upvote` or `answer.upvote` directly, instead of "manually" calling the `Rating.up` method and having to supply both user and item.

That can be done, provided you can store the current user somewhere that's accessible to the models. But let's keep it a little simpler and just go for a syntax like `question.upvote(user)`

To DRY out the "vote-enabled" models, try this:

```
# in app/concerns/votable.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module Votable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :rating, :as => :item
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def upvote(user)
      # Build the Rating record if it's missing
      build_rating if rating.nil?
      # Pass the user on
      rating.upvote user
    end

    def downvote(user)
      build_rating if rating.nil?
      rating.downvote user
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in a record that users can vote on, include that concern:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Votable
  # ...
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Votable
  # ...
end
```

Now the `Question` and `Answer` records will automatically build their own `Rating` record, if they don't have one already, and then pass the upvote/downvote calls on to that rating record.

As for `Rating` itself, here's what I'd do (I've changed the attribute names a little, but you can of course keep using yours):

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
  # Serialize stuff as straight-up Array
  serialize :upvoters, Array
  serialize :downvoters, Array
  # Create arrays after record initialization, so they're not nil on new records
  after_initialize :initialize_voters
  # Update the "owner's" rating cache after every save
  after_save :update_item

  # Note: No attr_accessible at all; it's not needed.

  # I'll skip the comments, as this should all be very easily readable.

  def upvote(user)
    if upvoted_by?(user)
      decrement :rating
      remove_upvoter(user)
    elsif downvoted_by?(user)
      increment :rating, 2
      add_upvoter user
      remove_downvoter user
    else
      increment :rating
      add_upvoter user
    end
    save
  end

  def downvote(user)
    if downvoted_by?(user)
      increment :rating
      remove_downvoter user
    elsif upvoted_by?(user)
      decrement :rating, 2
      remove_upvoter user
      add_downvoter user
    else
      decrement :rating
      add_downvoter user
    end
    save
  end

  def upvoted_by?(user)
    upvoters.include? user.id
  end

  def downvoted_by?(user)
    downvoters.include? user.id
  end

  private

    def add_upvoter(user)
      upvoters << user.id
    end

    def add_downvoter(user)
      downvoters << user.id
    end

    def remove_upvoter(user)
      upvoters.delete user.id
    end

    def remove_downvoter(user)
      downvoters.delete user.id
    end

    def initialize_voters
      upvoters ||= []
      downvoters ||= []
    end

    def update_item
      if item.present?
        item.update_attribute :rating_value, rating
      end
    end

end
```

And that's pretty much it. Now you can do `Question.find(23).upvote(current_user)` or whatever, and it should work out.

---

**Going straight to the database**
Alternatively, I'd suggest using "raw" database queries instead of models with serialized attributes and all that. All you really need is a simple table. It doesn't need an `id` column or a model-layer abstraction. All it needs to is have 4 columns: `user_id`, `vote`, `item_type`, and `item_id`. You can skip ActiveRecord models and such, since all you need to do is check for a certain user/item combo.

Make `user_id`, `item_id` and `item_type` the primary key (or add a uniqueness constraint) and you can do the entire logic in SQL (at least MySQL). If, for instance, user 23 votes on answer 42, it'd look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `votes` (`user_id`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `vote`)
VALUES (23, 42, "Answer", X)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `vote`=IF(`vote`=X, 0, X);
```

where `X` is `1` for an upvote, or `-1` for a downvote. That's actually all the upvote/downvote logic in one query.

Right after that, update the total rating for the post:

```
UPDATE `answers`
SET `rating_value`=(
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`vote`), 0)
  FROM `votes`
  WHERE `item_id`=42 AND `item_type`= "Answer"
)
WHERE id=42;
```

From time to time, you may want to do some clean-up to keep the table a little leaner (i.e. delete rows where the vote is zero, or when an associated item is deleted), but otherwise you should have a pretty robust solution with none of the overhead of Rails and ActiveRecord. And it can all be abstracted into a mixin like the concern above, and you can easily add the `upvoted_by?(user)`/`downvoted_by?(user)` methods there too with some simple SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `vote`<>0 AND `user_id`=23 AND `item_id`=42 AND `item_type`="Answer";
```